# Повторить формулу из Матлаба на Питоне

Tags: python, matlab

В матлабе есть формула

```
cvDelta = sdDelta.^2/delta;
```

где `sdDelta` и `delta`- массивы. 
В результате выполнения получаем *скаляр* (**число, а НЕ МАССИВ**).
В Питоне необходимо повторить эту формулу, но в результате получаю массив, вместо скалярного значения. Вот мой код.

```
cvDelta = sdDelta ** 2 / delta
```

Подозреваю, что дело в том, что в Питоне как-то по-другому происходят операции с массивами.

Comment: А что означает операция массив (вектор) / массив ? Чтобы получить скаляр нужны вектора одного размера и transpose(v1)*v2

Comment: используйте NumPy или ScientificPython

Comment: @m9_psy Массивы одного размера. Я сам не могу полностью понять, что происходит в Матлабовском отрывке кода.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa Использовал транспонирование, но в результате транспонирования и перемножения 2х массивов (из одной строки и одного столбца) получается массив данных.

Comment: вы можете привести два тестовых массива и результат вашей операции из матлаба для данных масивов?

Comment: операция деления в матлабе [означает совершенно иное](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)

Comment: эмуляция матлаб деления на python на английском [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007442/mrdivide-function-in-matlab-what-is-it-doing-and-how-can-i-do-it-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем проблема совершенно непонятно, но вот вам пример использования `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
B = np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])

print(A.T.dot(B))
# A и B не вектора размером (5,1), а массивы, поэтому numpy простит несоответствие размеров
print(A.dot(B))

>>> 50
>>> 50

A = np.array([[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]])
B = np.array([[5], [5], [5], [5], [5]])

# Не работает из-за несоответствия размеров - нельзя умножить (5,1) на (5,1)
print(A.dot(B))
```

В простейших случаях можно обойтись и без `numpy`, но по скорости наивное решение и операции `numpy` совершенно несравнимы - `numpy` обычно быстрее в разы:

```
A = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
B = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

assert(len(A) == len(B))

print(sum([A[index] * B[index] for index in range(len(A))]))

>>> 50
```

Comment: Ценю ваш ответ! `.dot` - скалярное произведение. Пожалуйста, помогите с конкретно моим примером, где происходит возведение массива в степень, а затем деление на другой массив. `cvDelta = sdDelta ** 2 / delta` - нужен скалярный результат.

Comment: @EmptyMan, У векторов нет такой операции. Есть деление на число, но деление на вектор? Как это геометрически представить? Можно представить только поэлементное деление.